# Drupal - "Access denied" for anonymous user

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-permissions

I installed Drupal(7.31) on an xampp server (in localhost). Then created some new contents as pages with menu items. Now when I logout and try to access that page, "Access denied" message is shown.

[admin view](http://oi61.tinypic.com/2lbolep.jpg)

[anonimous view](http://oi58.tinypic.com/qx0576.jpg)

Can someone tell me how to allow public access to a page?

Comment: what type of content did you create? What is the front page set to?

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I added a "basic page" (admin menu > Content > Add content > basic page). In the home page, I ticked "published" and "promoted to front page" as publishing options. In the about me page, I ticked only "published". (see the links given in the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. You have to visit "Administration » People". There you can change permissions and define user roles. If you give "View published content" permissions to "anonymous" user, the pages can be accessed by anonymous.

Comment: Also @Sampath Liyanage, just for your information, there is a good module available in Drupal 7 which allows admin to provide permission to view nodes content type wise. Check out [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_view_permissions)

Answer (score 0):

I want to add on. I had the same issue on Drupal 10, but I'm using Groups. It seems that the anonymous user view permissions on content is disabled by default. If you want anonymous users to see content created within Groups, you need to enable that in the group type configuration.
The permission is located at
`/admin/group/types/manage/{group_type}/permissions`

Under the content types assigned to the group type, you will see permissions that look like:
[Entity: View any content item entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErTET.png)